# Google Maps Static API - Custom zoom with markers

Tags: google-maps

I am creating an application that downloads images from maps using the Google Maps Static API. I would want to decide the zoom level when having markers on the map (right now the zoom is set automatically so that all markers are shown in the image). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#URL_Parameters), you can use the center and zoom parameters to configure the map (they aren't **required** with markers):

> **Location Parameters**
>
> - **center** (required if markers not present) defines the center of the map, equidistant from all edges of the map. This parameter takes a location as either a comma-separated {latitude,longitude} pair (e.g. "40.714728,-73.998672") or a string address (e.g. "city hall, new york, ny") identifying a unique location on the face of the earth. For more information, see Locations below.
> - **zoom** (required if markers not present) defines the zoom level of the map, which determines the magnification level of the map. This parameter takes a numerical value corresponding to the zoom level of the region desired. For more information, see zoom levels below.

**example URL:**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=42,-72&zoom=5&size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222&format=jpg
```

**resulting image:**

[image: static map]

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now the zoom is set automatically so that all markers are shown in the image

You are halfway there. Once done, get the resulting the zoom level: `map.getZoom();`

However, I think your app violates [Google's terms](http://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html) as it is forbidden to copy their content.